# How to calculate the limit of $(tu^{\alpha} + (1-t) v^{\alpha})^{1/\alpha}$ when $\alpha\to0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

as written in the subject, I'm interested in a proof of

$$\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \left( tu^{\alpha} + (1-t)v^{\alpha} \right)^{1/\alpha} = u^t v^{1-t},$$

where $t \in [0,1]$ and $u,v\geq0$. Can anybody help me out or give a hint?

Thanks in advance!

**Background:**

I came across the definition of $\alpha$-concave measures, where the quantity

$$M_{\alpha,t}(u,v) = \left( (1-t) u^{\alpha} + t v^{\alpha} \right)^{1/\alpha}$$

plays a role. Here, $t \in [0,1]$, $u,v > 0$ and $\alpha \in [-\infty,\infty]$, where for the cases $\alpha \in \left\{ 0, \pm \infty \right\}$ one *defines* $M_{-\infty,t}(u,v) = \min \left\{ u,v \right\}$, $M_{0,t}(u,v) = u^{1-t}v^t$ and $M_{\infty,t}(u,v) = \max \left\{ u,v \right\}$. It is clear to me that

$$M_{\pm \infty,t}(u,v) = \lim_{\alpha \to \pm \infty } M_{\alpha,t}(u,v)$$

and I assume the same relation holds at zero but don't see how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $0<t<1$ and $u,v>0.$ Consider $f(x)=(tu^{x} + (1-t) v^{x})^{1/x}.$ We have that $$\ln f(x)=\frac{\ln(tu^{x} + (1-t) v^{x})}{x}.$$ We have, using L'Hôpital's rule, that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \ln f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{tu^x\ln u+(1-t)v^x\ln v}{tu^{x} + (1-t) v^{x}}=t\ln u+(1-t)\ln v=\ln (u^tv^{1-t}).$$ Thus we are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot, nice and easy!